# Javascript - Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Date' and 'Moment'

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to compare last 30 mins data and display in UI. Datetime needs be UTC. I tried using Moment but i am getting error

```
Javascript - Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Date' and 'Moment'.
```

Below is my code :

```
  let d = moment();
      let d_utc = moment.utc();
      var customDate = new Date();
      d_utc.minutes(-30);  

      filteredData = filteredData.filter((category) => {
        return category.uploaded_time  > d_utc;
      });
```

Comment: why are you using two different datetime types? you can use `moment.isAfter()` to compare moment datetimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to compare a `Date` to an instance of a `Moment` with a `Date`, you need to convert them both to the same date.

You can call `.toDate()` to convert a moment to a Date or `moment(date)` to convert a Date to a Moment.

```
return category.uploaded_time > d_utc.toDate()
```

JavaScript doesn't have operator overrides, so the safest way to compare `Moments` is using `diff`:

```
return moment(category.uploaded_time).diff(d_utc) > 0
```

Comment: How to get a UTC Date from Moment ?

Comment: `moment.utc().toDate();`

Comment: moment.utc().toDate() gives me Tue Nov 22 2022 21:17:27 GMT-0800

Comment: var dateTime_now = new Date();
var dateTime_now_utc_str = dateTime_now.toISOString();
this gives me proper UTC.

Answer (score 0):

At the documentation in [get+set section](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) you can compare the seconds

Examplet in documentation

```
moment.utc().seconds(30).valueOf() === new Date().setUTCSeconds(30);
```

Your code should be

```
 let d_utc = moment.utc();
       let d_utc = moment.utc().minutes(-30).valueOf();

      filteredData = filteredData.filter((category) => {
        return category.uploaded_time.getUTCSeconds()  > d_utc;
      });
```

Also there is a [query section](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) you  can check it

Comment: For line 2 i am getting error Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Moment'